# Crosstalk on PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I just had a PCB fabricated and noticed a stupid mistake only after it had arrived. A chip was accidentally excluded from the data bus due to slightly different net names in the schematic. I had to solder jumpers to link it in and the results weren't pretty.

[image]

I used the glue so that the wires wouldnt come loose from the solder joints. It works. Mostly. Occasionally, I get a particular bit on the bus -- D5 in an 8-bit bus, specifically -- that either stays permanently HIGH or permanently LOW (I can tell from what I read from SRAM) till I fiddle with the jumpers and it's back to normal. D5 is the blue jumper all by itself near the top of the image; I separated it from the others after I noticed the problem. I've noticed there's a GND solder joint close to it, that whenever I make the jumper lie flat on that joint (or just lie flat on the GND plane), it seems to make the problem go away.

I'm thinking of making this a permanent fix (with more glue) so what I'd like to know is, if this is a crosstalk problem like I think and if this solution is enough to make the problem go away, as ordering another set of PCBs is not an option.

Comment: I think the problem is the excess length you have used in doing the wiring. Since all the components are through hole they are probably not very fast.  In such arrangements I've never needed to use twisted pair for up to 50MHz CPUs.  As suggested by Tony use the AWG30 wire with polyurethane insulation that can be melted by the soldering iron.  Keep the distance short and keep the wire close to the PCB (it looks like you have  a reasonable amount of ground plane present).  I normally use Manhattan routing even though it isn't the shortest.  After wiring and testing you can glue the wire down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the signal will ring a lot with those very inductive wires.

- **Use AWG30 magnet wire instead** with a tiny drop of crazy glue to tack long wires to PCB
- **for better signal integrity make twisted pair with near logic gnd. = 4 twist/cm**
- If you order green magnet wire for Gnd it is easier to see. Reddish for signal.
- Solder iron can burn thru varnish to pre-tin ends or use special dip or scrape.
- wire should be almost shortest path and tacked to board.

http://www.edn.com/design/test-and-measurement/4318657/Tiny-twisted-pair-transmission-line-solves-test-fixture-woes

Comment: Thanks. Wish I'd known all this before I went this far. Truth is, I'd rather not mess with the other wires; I've worked long enough on this that I'm bored with it and just want to get it working and submit with minimum fuss.  I'll try tacking the errant cable to the board, maybe the others too, and see if it solves the problem. If it doesn't, then I'll tear it apart.

Comment: Scope signal for quality

Comment: Don't have a scope yet. Though I hope I'll be able to buy one very soon. Will pray to Ohm that I won't *need* one till this project is done.

Answer (score 2):

Board rework must be done with care.

Hanging wires for reworking board traces are bad in two ways:

- Poor signal integrity as Tony said.
- Wires ripped off due to unvoluntary move or even have your board and whole setup dragged by an armrest. Don't laugh ! It really happens !

Here are some examples of neat reworking:

[image: Rework_01]  [image: Rework_02]

(Going over the oscillator is not the best thing to do but these are discrete signals)

Comment: Thanks. I get your point entirely. It also doesnt help that my jumpers are "springy". If I have to rip it up again, I'll keep this in mind.